# как начать повреждать картинку 640x480 с середины, не с конца

Tags: python

не судите меня по странному названиям переменных

проблема в том, что если я вставляю картинку (.bmp) то всегда повреждения в конце. как можно исправить это, не задевая настройки картинки?

(если это вообще возможно, то как я могу ускорить рождение 7мб файла?)

```
import sys as s
import random as r
import os

def main():
    name = s.argv[1]
    file = open(name, mode='rb')
    ex = os.path.splitext(name)
    con = file.read()
    c = 0
    c2 = 40 # стартовая позиция (дальше она задаётся случайно)
    ba = 0
    e = b'' # -end

    for u in con.decode('ansi'):
        if c==c2 or ba>1:
            try:   e += chr(r.randint(0,128)).encode('ansi')
            except:e += u.encode('ansi')
            c2 = r.randint(0,200)
            ba = r.randint(0,110)
            c = 0
        else:
            e += u.encode('ansi')
        ba -= 1
        c += 1
    a = open(f'output{r.randint(0,2**31)}{ex[1]}', mode='wb')
    file.close()
    a.write(e)
    a.close()
main()
```

> ВНИМАНИЕ: чтобы увидеть результат программы, впихнуть это:

*Вход:*
[image: Вход]

*Выход:*
[image: Выход]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: происходит так потому, что вы читаете файл, а читается он с конца. если вы хотите провернуть подобное с середины, вам нужно разбить его на две части и руинить их по очереди.